# Munkres Python Package not generating maximum total

Tags: python, algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

I am currently writing an algorithm to match users by compatibility score. So each user has a compatibility score with each of the other users. The goal is to maximize the total compatibility score. I am using the [munkres](http://software.clapper.org/munkres/) python package to get the indices and then filtering the duplicates. (i.e if user1 matches with user2, we remove the match with user2 and user1).

Here is an example matrix: (DISALLOWED in place where a user cannot be matched with themselves.)

```py
matrix = [[DISALLOWED, 2, 5, 7, 13, 10],
         [2, DISALLOWED, 25, 13, 5, 14],
         [5, 25, DISALLOWED, 21, 100, 17],
         [7, 13, 21, DISALLOWED, 70, 2],
         [13, 5, 100, 70, DISALLOWED, 200],
         [10, 14, 17, 2, 200, DISALLOWED]]
```

Here is what I have tried. It works for this smaller matrix example I gave but is not giving the optimal score for the larger dataset. I know the total score is not optimal as a non-optimized algorithm (simply sorting the scores and matching each user in order) is generating a much higher score.

```py
def optimize(matrix):
    optimal_matrix = make_cost_matrix(matrix, lambda cost: (sys.maxsize - cost) if
                                    (cost != DISALLOWED) else DISALLOWED)

    m = Munkres()
    indexes = m.compute(optimal_matrix)
    
    matches = []
    for row, column in indexes:
        value = matrix[row][column]
        match = [row, column, value]
        matches.append(match)

    matches.sort(key=thirdValue, reverse=True)

    seen = []
    total = 0
    for match in matches:

        if match[0] not in seen and match[1] not in seen:
            total += match[2]
            seen.append(match[0])
            seen.append(match[1])
    print(total)
```

Is there a certain matrix that would break my code? Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess munkres implements the Hungarian algorithm, but you're trying to solve a general matching problem, which calls for the Blossom algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The Hungarian Algorithm is for "bipartite" graphs, but you don't have a bipartite graph. A bipartite graph is one in which you have two distinct sets of nodes. For example: assigning workers to jobs. Nodes within a set do not connect to each other; a worker can be assigned to a job, or a job to a worker, but workers are not assigned to workers nor jobs assigned to jobs. In your case you are trying to assign users *to other users*. That is, you only have one set, not two.

By marking the diagonal `DISALLOWED` you are preventing a user from being matched with themselves, but you aren't preventing a user from being matched with more than one other user. For example, with only four users who all have the same compatibility:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** |
| **A** |  | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **B** | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |
| **C** | 0 | 0 |  | 0 |
| **D** | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

A matched with C
B matched with D
C matched with B
D matched with A

is a valid result for the Hungarian algorithm, but is not valid for your situation. I don't know that this is what's happening, but it *could* happen, so you need to use a different algorithm.

Comment: When I perform the matching no user is matched more than once so it doesn't seem to be the problem. That being said, I am wondering what algorithm would be better suited for this problem?

Comment: I haven't looked into it too much, but you could try Edmonds' Blossom Algorithm as @DavidEisenstat mentioned in a comment on your question. Finding a smaller example that doesn't work would also help.